# Converting a object list (from DB) to a sitemapdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, hierarchy

I am working with a Folder list object, that has a list of folder obj's with a `name`, `ID`, and `parentID`.  I am trying to fill out a `asp:TreeView` control but the datasource of a `List<>` is not the same as a `IHeiraricialDataSource`..

Whats a good way to convert the list to a `IHeiraricalDataSource` without using Linq??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `IHierarchicalDataSource` and `HierarchicalDataSourceControl`. Take a look at the examples section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.hierarchicaldatasourcecontrol.aspx